# .htaccess direct access to folder forbidden but sibgle image show available

Tags: .htaccess

I have an folder /img

I want that isn't allowed to watch alle pictures via /img
But I want to allow img/picture1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

To deny direct access to img folder, you can use

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /img/.*
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
RewriteRule ^(.+\.gpg|png|gif)$ /img/$1 [L]
```

This will rewrite **/foo.png** to **/img/foo.png** but you will get 403 error if you request **/img/foo.png**